# C++ std::vector segfault when using erase(), ok when using pop_back() with g++

Tags: c++, vector

Please consider the following code:

```
vector<int> myVector;
myVector.push_back(10);
myVector.erase(myVector.end());
```

This code compiles and runs fine on Windows (VisualStudio), but results in a segfault on Linux when compiled with g++. Replacing erase with pop_back solves the problem on Linux.

Does anyone know why the behaviour is different on the two platforms, and what behaviour to consider correct.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`end()` typically returns an invalid position in the array (one beyond the end).

`pop_back()` removes the last item in the vector.

If you want to erase, you have to do `erase(end() - 1);` here `end() - 1` returns an iterator to the last item.

`erase(end())` should invoke UB - which I think is correct...

EDIT: as Martin pointed out, before calling `erase(end() - 1)`, check that the vector is not empty!

Comment: More elegant IMHO: `myVector.erase(myVector.rbegin());`, +1 btw.

Comment: @AraK, I don't think in the current standard erase can work with reverse iterators, sadly this approach is not possible - so `pop_back()` is actually more elegant :)

Comment: @Nim Ahh, you're right! I mistakingly thought that end() returns the iterator to the last item. I am still not quite sure why it worked when I ran it on Windows though...

Comment: ravil, probably it didn't, it just failed to fail.

Comment: Sorry guys, I wrote it from the top of my mind, but I didn't try it out.

Comment: Sorry, it did in fact fail on Windows as well.. I just took this code out of scope, and assumed that it will fail as well. Anyways, thanks for your answers everyone!!

Comment: be careful of `end() - 1`. If the vector is empty then that's still an invalid location.

Answer (score 0):

`end()` points to nowhere, that is beyond the end.

Answer (score 0):

`myVector.end()` does not point to the last element of the vector. It points *past* the last element of the vector. I am not sure, though, if this qualifies as undefined behavior (if it does, then it is reasonable that Windows and Linux behave differently).

Answer (score 0):

`myVector.end()` gives you an iterator to right *after* the last element in your vector. As there isn't anything there, calling erase on it doesn't make much sense.

I am curious to find out exactly what Visual Studio is doing when you call that though. Run some tests to see if it is actually erasing the `10` from your vector, or if it is just gracefully ignoring your incorrect request.