# Correctly handling std::list erase with list size 1

Tags: c++, stl, stdlist

Consider the following:

```
for (it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ++it) {
    if (!(*it)->alive) {
        it = list.erase(it);
    }
}
```

this works fine as long as `list.size() > 1`. Once the list contains only one element, the call to erase segfaults. I am assuming because there is no next element. At least, that's the behavior I am observing.
Is there a correct way to handle this? Perhaps an entirely different approach?

As you can see I don't want to clear the list instantly. I want to just remove elements as they die and this works fine until it deletes the last element.

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674015/c-stdvector-segfault-when-using-erase-ok-when-using-pop-back-with-g

Comment: BTW, don't you have a memory leak here? Seems that the list contains pointers, and you erase them without deleting first. Are the pointed objects still accessible?

Comment: The pointers are still available from another list. When they die they go to the dead list and then get recycled onto the live list when needed. Saves some alloc and dealloc cycles.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following will work correctly:

```
for (it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ) {
    if (!(*it)->alive) {
        it = list.erase(it);
    } else {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

The problem is not just with certain sizes. In your example, you are **skipping** an element every time you remove one. Think about it.

If the element is not "alive", then you do: `it = list.erase(it);`, which removes the element and sets `it` to the one that follows it. **then your loop performs `++it`**, which skips the next one, possibly skipping `end()`!

This is not just an issue with skipping `end()`, you were skipping others too, but removing the last element in the list will likely yield a crash.

Comment: Thanks. Strange thing is that my code above does work on linux compiled with g++ but seems to crash on my Mac at home. I will need to double check this. But I will try your solution to see if it fixes the issue on the Mac.

Comment: I have a feeling that by "working" you mean "doesn't crash" :-). Your code had undefined behavior which means it was allowed to appear to do anything. Also, the issue is not just with the end of the loop, it was skipping an element every time you removed one. It would only crash if you happened to remove the last one.

Comment: Exactly :) - Makes sense now. Thanks